# not enough values insert with register type Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: sql, insert, oracle-sqldeveloper, record

I am trying to make a variable of a custom record type, set values to it, then insert it into a table.
I am having difficulties, and I do not know where I am wrong.
I checked the columns in the table and they are all the not-nullable colums in the register type.
Yet I get a "not enough values" error.
I'm working in SQL Developer.
Here is my code:

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
  TYPE ang_record IS RECORD
    (cod employees.employee_id%TYPE,
    nume employees.last_name%TYPE,
    email employees.email%TYPE,
    h_date employees.hire_date%TYPE,
    job_id employees.job_id%TYPE,
    sal employees.salary%TYPE,
    dept employees.department_id%TYPE);
  v_ang ang_record;
BEGIN
  v_ang.cod := 500;
  v_ang.nume := 'Profeanu';
  v_ang.email := 'ileana.profeanu@gmail.com';
  v_ang.h_date := SYSDATE;
  v_ang.job_id := 'SH_CLERK';
  v_ang.sal := 2000;
  v_ang.dept := 50;
  INSERT INTO empil (employee_id, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id, salary, department_id)
  VALUES v_ang;
END;
/
ROLLBACK;
```

Comment: Why are the used tables (employees and empil) different?

Comment: employees is the table we make queries on, empil is the table we can modify (they are the same type)

Comment: Why do you want this to do? If you modify empil and query employees then  the data is outdated.

Comment: it's for learning purposes! i'm still a student, and we don't have permissions to modify employees

Comment: Oke. So it is better that you make a plsql table of the empil table. Just like you did with the employee the table. Then assign the desired values to the empil plsql table. For example v_emp.employee_id := 500; and so on. See my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a record type of the employees table. And you want to use this type to insert a record into the empil table. You have mixed up the two ways to achieve this.
First:

```
    set serveroutput on;

        DECLARE
          TYPE ang_record IS RECORD
            (cod employees.employee_id%TYPE,
            nume employees.last_name%TYPE,
            email employees.email%TYPE,
            h_date employees.hire_date%TYPE,
            job_id employees.job_id%TYPE,
            sal employees.salary%TYPE,
            dept employees.department_id%TYPE);
          v_ang ang_record;
        BEGIN
          v_ang.cod := 500;
          v_ang.nume := 'Profeanu';
          v_ang.email := 'ileana.profeanu@gmail.com';
          v_ang.h_date := SYSDATE;
          v_ang.job_id := 'SH_CLERK';
          v_ang.sal := 2000;
          v_ang.dept := 50;
          INSERT INTO empil (employee_id, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id, salary, department_id)
          VALUES (v_ang.code, v_ang.nume, v_ang.email, v_ang.h_date, v_ang.job_id, v_ang.sal, v_ang.dept);
        END;
        /
        ROLLBACK;
```

Second:

```
   set serveroutput on;

        DECLARE
          v_ang    r_empil%rowtype;
        BEGIN
          v_ang.employee_id := 500;
          v_ang.last_name := 'Profeanu';
          v_ang.email := 'ileana.profeanu@gmail.com';
          v_ang.hire_date := SYSDATE;
          v_ang.job_id := 'SH_CLERK';
          v_ang.salary := 2000;
          v_ang.department_id := 50;
          INSERT INTO empil (employee_id, last_name, email, hire_date, job_id, salary, department_id)
          VALUES v_ang;
        END;
        /
        ROLLBACK;
```

I hope that I have made it clear for you.

Good luck with your studies!!!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that SQL treats the data type object separately than it does the data type members. v_ang is considered a single item even though it consists of multiple sub elements.

You either need to create a table who's column is of type ang_record, or insert the elements individually like this.

```
INSERT INTO empil (employee_id, last_name, email, hire_date, 
                   job_id, salary, department_id)
VALUES (v_ang.employee_id, v_ang.last_name, v_ang.email, 
        v_ang.hire_date, v_ang.job_id, v_ang.salary, 
        v_ang.department_id);
```